# QTreeView Model of a plain array

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

I have a very big plain array of data with numbers. I want to use `QTreeView` and Model/View approach to show the data grouped in tree nodes with specific parameters, ex. data value < 10, data value < 100, data value < 1000.

Official Tree Model example shows how to use hierarchical data structure for item nodes that is bad option for me.

I tried to write the model myself from `QAbstractItemModel` but I can't even realize how to write `parent()` method for group nodes (<10, <100, <1000) and their child nodes, for example.

Is it event possible to write such a model?

Comment: Hi there, welcome to SO. Who better than you can guess if your idea is possible? I advise you post the code of what you did try, and possibly a more graphic view of what you want to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create "artificial" parents, which are model indexes with no value but just correspond to the parent of items with Data Value < 100.

Each item with a data value < 100 will refer to the same parent. And this parent will need to give all those items when asked for its children (and the number of children with `rowCount()` applied on it).

```
bool MyModel::isCategory(const QModelIndex &index) const
{
    /* Based on your internal tracking of indexes, return if this is 
       a category (with children), false if not */
}

int MyModel::rowCount(const QModelIndex & parent) const
{
    if (!parent.isValid()) {
        /* This is top level */
        /* Return the number of different categories at top level */
    }
    if (isCategory(parent)) {
        /* This is a parent category (for example items with data value < 100 */
        /* Return the number of indexes under it */
    }
    /* This is a child element with just data in it, no children */
    return 0;
}

QModelIndex MyModel::index(int row, int column, const QModelIndex & parent) const
{
    if (!parent.isValid()) {
        /* Return QModelIndex corresponding to the nth global category, with n = row */
    }
    /* return the nth sub-element of the category represented by parent, with n = row */
}

QModelIndex QAbstractItemModel::parent(const QModelIndex & index) const
{
    /* If index is a top level category, return an empty QModelIndex */
    /* Otherwise return the QModelIndex corresponding to the bigger category */
}
```

Provide a minimal code sample on a simplified case where your code is not working if this is still not enough.

Comment: Thank you so much. I have finally made index with 2 highest bits for type of virtual group and element index. By the way one can read number of a row to know its position in subarray, for example. Finally I have coded the model of a complex data consisting of several plan arrays wich elements are connected with each other.